Sequence of function (measure theory)
Let $g$ be a integrable function on a set $E$ and suppose that $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions such that $|f_n(x)|\leq g(x)$ a.e. on $E.$ Then show that
$$\int_E \liminf f_n \leq \liminf \int_E f_n \leq \limsup \int_E f_n \leq \int_E \limsup f_n.$$
What I am trying is the following:
I consider the sequence $f_n+g$ and $g-f_n$ and using Fatous lemma, i derived some inequalities. But the last two inequalities didn't come.

$\lim \inf$ is always $\le \lim \sup$. No proof is required for this part. For the last inequality change $f_n$ to $-f_n$ in the first inequlaity.

Since $g$ be a integrable function on a set $E$, we have $\int_E g \neq \pm \infty$. Since  $|f_n(x)|\leq g(x)$ a.e. on $E$, we have $g+f_n \geqslant 0$ a.e. on $E$ and $g-f_n \geqslant 0$ a.e. on $E$. Using Fatou's lemma, we have
$$\int_E g + \int_E \liminf f_n = \int_E \liminf (g + f_n) \leq \liminf \int_E (g+f_n)= \int_E g + \liminf \int_E f_n$$
Since $\int_E g \neq \pm \infty$, we have
$$\int_E \liminf f_n  \leq \liminf \int_E f_n$$
(continue)

Now, using again Fatou's lemma, and the fact that $\liminf (-f_n) = - \limsup f_n$,  we have
$$\int_E g - \int_E \limsup f_n = \int_E \liminf (g - f_n) \leq \liminf \int_E (g-f_n)= \int_E g - \limsup \int_E f_n$$
Since $\int_E g \neq \pm \infty$, we have
$$-\int_E \limsup f_n  \leq - \limsup \int_E f_n$$
So
$$ \limsup \int_E f_n \leq \int_E \limsup f_n$$
And finally, it is immediate that
$$\liminf \int_E f_n \leq \limsup \int_E f_n $$
